# Cin.Ignore() is not working

Tags: c++, cin

Here I have a code:

```
cout << "Press Enter To Exit...";
cin.ignore();
```

this program will execute and will wait till you press enter and then it will exit.
now see this code:

```
int m;
cin >> m;
cout << "Press Enter To Exit...";
cin.ignore();
```

this time after entering a number for saving in "m" the program will exit without waiting for cin.ignore command which waits for pressing enter.

I mean if you use cin command before cin.ignore, the cin.ignore command will skip. why? and what should I do for fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
std::cin.sync(); std::cin.get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Beside I can simply use cin.ignore(); two times and it will solve the problem, something like this: cout << "Press Enter To Exit...";
cin.ignore();
cin.ignore();

Comment: If there is nothing in the input buffer, the user will have to enter two characters for that to work, whereas `sync` clears any left and then `get` reads until the user hits enter.

Comment: [`cin.sync()`'s discarding unprocessed input is MSVC specific](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sync#Notes).

Answer (score 5):

`cin.ignore()` basically clears any input left in memory. In the first piece of code, you did not input anything, hence it will have nothing to clear and because of that it waits for you to input something.
In the second piece of code you used the `>>` operator which gets formated input but leaves the end line character `'\n'` (the one that gets stored when you press ENTER) wandering in the input buffer. When you call cin.ignore() it then does it job and clears that same buffer.As it already did what he was called to it simply lets the program continue (in this case to the end). Remember `cin.ignore()` is for clearing the input buffer(small piece of memory that holds the input) if you want the user to input something before the program moves on use `cin.get()`.

You should also know this:

If using:

->`cin<<` you should call cin.ignore() afterwards because it does not consume the end line character '\n' which will be consumed next time you ask for input causing unwanted results
such as the program not waiting for you to input anything.

->`cin.get()` you should not call cin.ignore() because it consumes the '\n'

->`getline(cin,yourstring)` (gets a whole input line including the end line character) you should also not use cin.ignore()

Comment: Thanks for your complete reply, do you know any better way for pressing enter to exit?

Comment: no. As far as I know cin.get() is the best cross-platform option avaible. (still I'm no c++ pro).

Comment: Thanks. I have searched and tried many options. This answer clears all confusions.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
int m;
cin >> m;
cin.ignore();

cout << "Press Enter To Exit...";
cin.ignore();
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use `cin >> m` you type value of m and then press enter, the enter `'\n'` goes into buffer and `cin.ignore();` ignores it and program ends.