# C++ can't have cin.ignore() after cin?

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue using cin.ignore(), if I use it after a cin >> statement it doesn't seem to work and ends the program instead. 
Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int number ;
int main () {
    cin >> number;
    cout << number;
    cin.ignore()
    return 0;
}
```

I am typing " 4 " (without quotes) at the prompt. I'm expecting it to prompt for an int (which it does) and then display that int until the user presses enter again. However as soon as I press enter on the first prompt the program closes. If I replace the cin.ignore() with a new cin >> then it waits until I enter data at that prompt before closing, however this way I have to put data into the prompt, I can't just press enter to close it.

I read about putting cin.clear() after the cin input but that didn't help. If I replace cin.ignore() with cin >> num2; then it works fine. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the input you are using to test your program to the post.

Comment: Define "work". What do you expect of this program ? (which also cannot compile)

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What did you expect it to do that it didn't  do?

Comment: Hi, added my input to the question. I omitted some of the code to save on question size so I'll add the rest in as well.

Comment: You still haven't told us what you want it to do, or what it's doing wrong.

Comment: After you typed `4` at the prompt, what were you expecting to happen and what actually happened that you were not expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting it to prompt for an int (which it does) and then display that int until the user presses enter again. However as soon as I press enter on the first prompt the program closes. If I replace the cin.ignore() with a new cin >> then it waits until I enter data at that prompt before closing, however this way I have to put data into the prompt, I can't just press enter to close it.

Comment: Okay. The problem is that your code looks like what most people would want to do. It asks for a number and then the `ignore()` statement skips over the return character that is left in the input buffer that `>>` didn't extract. If you want the program to pause then you would have to call `ignore()` a second time.

Comment: `cin.ignore()` you missed `;`

Comment: The basic problem is that `cin >> number` only extracts the number but **not** the return character that follows it when you press the return key. That is why your `ignore();` call doesn't wait, it simply sees that character and ignores it.

Comment: @tomh1012 please put your comment into the original question so we know what you're asking when reading the question.

Comment: Ah I see! Adding a second ignore() did the trick, thanks for your help /explanation, that makes a lot of sense

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349575/cin-ignore-is-not-working (but I can't change my close vote)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cin.Ignore() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349575/cin-ignore-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your input stream and ignore the rest of it if for example your user did not enter a valid `int` type as input. The `while` loop will not exit until `number` contains an actual integer. After that, if you want the program to wait until the user presses "Enter" or any other key, you can just call `ignore` again.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>    

int main()
{
    int number;
    // we need to enforce that the input can be stored as `int` type
    while(!(std::cin >> number))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid value! Please enter a number." << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout << "Your number is: " << number << std::endl;

    // wait for user to press Enter before exiting
    // you can do this with ignore() x2 once for the newline
    // and then again for more user input
    std::cout << "Press Enter to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: asking for clarifications are made via comments, not answers.